# What is this question worth?

Tags: discussion

I up-voted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118980/statistics-likelihood-ratio-stat) and its vote total remains $-1$.  This seems like newbie-biting.  Could others opine on this particular question.

Comment: Most likely the people who downvoted the original version did not see that it was edited. Have you tried @-pinging some of the other users who commented on the question? Since there are new edits, those who downvoted before now has the option to remove the downvote.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I'm tempted to after seeing the minimal effort/interaction from the OP. Your answer was helpful, MH... I wouldn't be that generous with such a user!

Comment: I don't think considerations of what the absolute vote total *ought to be* should determine whether or not you upvote a post. There is no notion of the true "worth" of any post, so your title is begging a meaningless question. (If a post is good but you think it deserves a score of 10 and it is currently at 20, will you downvote it?) See also [this previous post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2234/856).

Comment: @TheChaz : The question and answer are not only to be read by the one user who posted it.  The question deals with a theoretical point that always arises in a certain kind of theory-of-statistics course.  So others may benefit from it six weeks are five years hence.

Comment: Please forgive me for being so shortsighted!